# How do I route a variable to another page from a select list in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, selectlist, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

This likely has a simple solution but I've struggled for a while now.

I have a form with a select list, and I want to select an item and then send that item value to a new page using a button in the same form. For some reason I can't figure out how to save the item value, I don't know what I'm missing.

***Page 1 html***

```
<form method="post" class="container">
    <h4>Generate printable list by lab</h4>
    <div class="form-group form-row">
        <select asp-for="LabNumberToFilter" asp-items="Model.LabNumberListOptions" class="form-control col-md-2">
            <option value="">Select a lab number</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="LabNumberToFilter" class="text-danger"></span>
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg col-md-2" asp-page="./Page2"
               asp-route-labNumber="@Model.LabNumberToFilter" />Create List<a/>
    </div>
</form>
```

***Page 1 model***

```
[BindProperty]
public int LabNumberToFilter { get; set; }
public SelectList LabNumberListOptions { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync() {
     (…)
 
     LabNumberListOptions = new SelectList(_context.LabTours, nameof(LabTour.LabNumber), nameof(LabTour.LabNumber));

     return Page();
}
```

***Page 2 html***

```
@page "{labNumber:int?}"
(…)
```

***Page 2 model***

```
public int LabNumber { get; set; }

public IList<LabTour> LabTourList { get; set; }

public async Task OnGetAsync(int? labNumber)
{
    LabNumber = labNumber.Value;
    LabTourList = await _context.LabTours.Where(l => l.LabNumber == LabNumber).ToListAsync();
}
```

If I put a default value in for my `LabNumberToFilter`, the button routes the default value correctly, so the problem is that my select list doesn't save/use the new inputted value when I hit the button to redirect to page 2. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify an action in the form that points to page 2. You can do this either by explicitly setting the action attribute:

```
<form method="post" action="/Page2">
```

or by passing the page name to the asp=page attribute:

```
<form method="post" asp-page="/Page2">
```

Then in Page2, add the `[BindProperty]` attribute to a public property with the same name as the parameter specified by the `asp-for` attribute in the select element (`LabNumberToFilter`):

```
[BindProperty]
public int LabNumberToFilter { get; set; }
```

This will capture the posted value. You don't need the parameter in the handler method, or the route template.

Note that the form's method is `Post`, so the `OnGet` handler in page 2 will not execute.

See here for more background on model binding in Razor Pages: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

Comment: Thanks! Of course the best solution is always the least complicated... I just changed the ```<form method="get">``` and then added ```[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]``` to be able to use the ```OnGet``` handler. All the best

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a  [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

You will have to load it in a loop but then you can access the value from the input e.g.

```
    <form method="post">
         <input type="text" asp-for="LabNumberToFilter" list="labNumbers" placeholder="Select or enter a lab number"/>
         <datalist id="labNumbers">
                    @foreach (var labNum in Model.LabNumberListOptions)
                    {
                        <option value="@labNum"></option>
                    }
         </datalist>
         <button type="submit" ...
    </form>
```